# Looking for guidance for vb.net program to cleanup temp file directories for every user

Tags: vb.net, delete-file, temp, multiple-users

I am looking for some guidance on getting a function working for a program I am working on.

The function I am stuck on is meant to remove all files from multiple directories on a remote computer for all user profiles on that machine.

At the moment I am trying to get output to my textbox with all of the files in the directories and subdirectories before I added the file.delete().

All of the "items" are displaying as one letter characters as it is separating each letter in the filepath into a separate item (probably the way I did the `For..Each`).

I know I am making multiple noobie mistakes as I am very new to VB.net and am still very much in the learning stage but I am looking for some guidance.

I have been searching and pulling pieces together to get it working but have hit a wall, any help is appreciated!

Current Code:

```
   Private Sub Deltemp_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Deltemp.Click
    If Compname2.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("You didn't enter anything in the Computername field, please enter something then try again.")
        GoTo statementend
    End If
    Try
        If My.Computer.Network.Ping(Compname2.Text, 1000) Then
            PSoutput.Text = ""
        Else
            PSoutput.Text &= Compname2.Text + " is not connected to our network currently."
            GoTo statementend
        End If
        PSoutput.Text = ""
        Dim userpath As String = "\\" + Compname2.Text + "\c$\users\"
        Dim tempu(7) As String
        tempu(0) = "\AppData\Local\Temp\"
        tempu(1) = "\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\"
        tempu(2) = "\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Credentials"
        tempu(3) = "\AppData\Local\Temporary Internet Files\"
        tempu(4) = "\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Credentials"
        tempu(5) = "\AppData\Roaming\SUN"
        tempu(6) = "\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0"
        Dim fsd As Object
        fsd = FileIO.FileSystem.GetDirectories(userpath)
        For Each user In fsd
            Try
                Dim filepaths = FileIO.SpecialDirectories.AllUsersApplicationData()
                If user Like "*Default*" Or user Like "*.NET*" Or user Like "*All Users" Or user Like "*Public" Then
                    PSoutput.Text &= ""
                Else
                    Dim Fullpath = user + tempu(7)
                    For Each item In Fullpath
                        FileIO.FileSystem.GetFiles(Fullpath)
                        PSoutput.Text &= item.ToString + " was found" & Environment.NewLine
                    Next
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
                PSoutput.Text &= "A file was skipped for being in use or an exception occured" & Environment.NewLine
            End Try
        Next
    Catch
        MessageBox.Show("The machine/ip entered doesn't exist on our network or is an invalid entry")
    End Try
statementend:
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's this right here:

```
Dim Fullpath = user + tempu(7)
    For Each item In Fullpath '<<<<<<<<<
```

`Fullpath` appears to be a string, so when you do `For-Each` you're iterating through the characters in that string.

I think what you want is to create a new `DirectoryInfo`, get the files in that directory, and iterate through them.

```
dim directory = new System.io.DirectoryInfo(Fullpath)
For Each file in directory.GetFiles()
```

I recommend adding 'Option Strict' to the top of your code or enabling it for the project. Then the compiler will be more "strict" in requiring you to declare types, and then the compiler will force you to be more explicit about what types you're working with. It will highlight some errors to fix but it's worth it.

Comment: I knew it had to be something easy I was missing, thank you Scott!! - Extra question if you could, I notice that when I run it this way I get only the files in all of the directories, I also didn't see a get directories when I dot sourced directories, anyway to get all of the files inside all subdirectories included? Also thank you for the 'Option Strict' tip, I will get this implemented :)

Comment: No, you would need to recursively get the directories in each directory and get the files in each directory. So you're going to need one more method - you pass it a directory, then it gets all of the subdirectories in that directory and calls itself. That way it keeps going through all of the subdirectories until there are no more.

Comment: Here's [an example](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/306666) and [one more](http://www.coderslexicon.com/playing-with-recursive-directory-diving-in-vb-net/).

Comment: Awesome, thank you again for all of your help Scott!